# mod_rewrite overriding second RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running in to a mod_rewrite issue where the second rule in my .htaccess file is overriding the first. The .htaccess file in question looks like the one below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/appname

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/index.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

The issue that I'm seeing is this:

If I go directly to http://example.com/path/appname/api/v1/valid/endpoint the first RewriteRule triggers correctly and I get the result back from the API.

However, say I visit http://example.com/path/appname/app - a page which has been rewritten according to the second RewriteRule. This page makes AJAX requests to the api/v1 page. Those requests are instead directed through the second RewriteRule and send to my base index.php page.

I'm confused on how this could be, as my understanding is that the [L] flag prevents any further rules from being run once it matches and thus once any request that has 'api/v1' in it should catch that and stop checking for any further matches. What do I need to change in order for this to work correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Which means the first doesn't match. Check the exact URL in you console which the js accesses, or enable a `RewriteLog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exclude the segment path for the previous rule-set, so it is not processed again. Like this:

```
# Don't redirect/map when folders or files exist 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Exclude the previous path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api/v1/?   [NC]

# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]

RewriteRule . index.php                [L]

</IfModule>
```

Replace the last 4 lines in you question with the above lines.

Comment: Awesome, that works. I still don't really understand why I was able to get to the api section directly but the rewrite from the AJAX call couldn't.